# Python create a list of folders if it doesn't exist

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of folders if they don't exist.

I want to iterate through a list of directories and create them, but check each time if the directory exists.

This is my code:

```
# Create output subdirectories
folders = ['csv','excel','html', 'json']
for folder in folders:
    if not os.path.exists(output_files_path,folder):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(output_files_path,folder))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 767, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 708, in main
    mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Synchronoss Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 279, in mongo_export_to_file
    create_directories()
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Synchronoss Technologies\Desktop\important_folders\Jokefire\git\jf_cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 122, in create_directories
    if not os.path.exists(output_files_path,folder):
TypeError: exists() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `os.makedirs`

There is a keyword option `exist_ok`, if you set to true, will not overwrite it if the folder already exists.

`makedirs` can also create multiple subdirectories recursively in a single call. This seems to make your job a lot easier in my opinion.

If you're looking for how to call `os.path.exists` properly:

It seems like you're missing a `join` call:

```py
os.path.exists(os.path.join(output_files_path,folder))
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of `makedirs` creating multiple paths in a single call?

Comment: `os.makedirs("full/path/to/folder")` makes the `full`, `full/path`, `full/path/to`, `full/path/to/folder` folders

Comment: Oh ok. But I need to create several subdirectories in the same directory. That's why I'm iterating through a list.

Comment: that's fine. 1) I provide how to call `os.path.exists` and 2) `makedirs` is nice because it has `exists_ok`, so you will not need to check existence yourself

Comment: It can be used as `mkdir` is being used as well

Comment: I kind of combined the two answers to my question. This works fine!

`# Create output subdirectories
    folders = ['csv','excel','html', 'json']
    for folder in folders:
        full_path = os.path.join(output_files_path,folder)
        os.makedirs(full_path, exist_ok=True)`

Answer (score 3):

Just need to pass in the full path to os.path.exists instead of the path as two parameters.

```
for folder in folders:
    full_path = os.path.join(output_files_path,folder)
    if not os.path.exists(full_path):
        os.mkdir(full_path)
```